# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat:  1pm UTC / 8am EST on the 4th - now!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Friday the 4th at 1pm UTC, or 8am EST.**

[(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=3&day=4&year=2011&hour=13&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

[click here to join](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/323/unix-linux-town-hall-chat)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.<s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 1st-4th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=unix.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/323/unix-linux-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript and a summary will be available.

Comment: I'll just have had my wisdom teeth out the day before. My participation will depend slightly on my pain and medication levels. :)

Comment: @mattdm New [tagline](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline): Unix and Linux -- high medication levels recommended

Answer (score 2):

If you won't be able to attend the chat, add your question here!

1. What is your policy on migrating questions to Ask Ubuntu? ([Gilles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles))
2. A majority of the questions here would also be on-topic on Super User. What makes Unix SE different? ([Gilles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles))
3. How can Unix SE get more experts onboard? ([Gilles](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles))

Comment: @rebecca so are we supposed to answer these here? or are they going to get asked in the town hall meeting.

Comment: I think, actually, it might be more useful to ask those questions _as_ questions here on meta. As noted above, I might not be able to attend the chat either, and it's a little awkward to answer an answer.

Comment: @xeno I'll ask them in chat if nobody else does, so one way or another they'll end up there

Comment: @mattdm [Josh](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/users/1974/josh) makes digests of the chats and posts them on meta; you can add your answers to that (e.g. fluteflute did that on [Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest))

Answer (score 0):

As with the other town hall chats, I will be creating a "digest" version for the Unix & Linux Town Hall Chat. This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions and their answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests). Or for an example, look at the [AskUbuntu Town Hall Digest](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) or the [Gaming Town Hall Digest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1759/2252).

You can also discuss these digests with me in chat, in [the Town Hall Discussion room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/352/town-hall-discussion).

### [Here is the Digest version of the Town Hall Chat](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/495/1974)